# I'm debugging my flutter code on real device it show me error java 11

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\secon flutter deleting\shahy\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              9.0s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle. │
│                                                                               │
│ To get Java 11, update to the latest version of Android Studio on             │
│ https://developer.android.com/studio/install.                                 │
│                                                                               │
│ To check the Java version used by Flutter, run `flutter doctor -v`.           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Try doing what it says and download Java 11 (or later).  Are your PATH environment variables set correctly?

Comment: from where I should download my java 11 because I am using my VS Code editor. I have also Android studio but can you tell me where I download it in android studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s your place set up?

Is the gradle java version too low

```
JAVA_HOME D:\Android\Android Studio\jre
   %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for spotting my issue. now I am using VS Code and I had also downloaded my Android Studio. so how to upgrade it to java 11